# How to query (LINQ) multiple table association link?

Tags: linq

I have tables association such as (CaseClient is a bridge table):

- Cases has many CaseClients
- Client has many CaseClients
- ClientType has many CaseClient

The easiest way just use the view in database but I heard that with linq you can join this somehow?  Or should I just created view in the database and linq query agains that view?

I am appreciated your comment

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the Join method, from your bridging table and resolving each of your relationships.  E.g.

```
// Where CaseId and TypeId are your members of CaseClient
var x = caseClients.Join( cases, cc => cc.CaseId, c => c.Id)
                                .Join( types, cc => cc.TypeId, t => t.Id)
                                .Select();
```

Above code untested (so far) and from memory.  You may need to put a Select between the two joins.

Comment: The .Select is unnecessary (and maybe wrong, if I remember correctly) unless you have a selection function that extracts some subset of the joined columns.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an adaptation of what I did for a very similar situation.  Only the names have been changed to protect the innocent.

```
IEnumerable<Case> getCaseByClient(int client_id)
{
    var ret = from c in Cases
              join cc in CasesClients
                on c.Id equals cc.ClientId
              join cl in Clients
                on cc.ClientId equals client_id
              select c;
    return ret;
}
```

of course this assumes your client_id field is an int, but thats easy enough to modify.